# Jmeter TCP Raspberry Pi cache

Tags: linux, qt, caching, tcp, jmeter

I have written simple server in Qt, which responses for TCP requests with simple string (few bytes), the response and request are constant sets of data. I have compiled it on Raspberry Pi (Arch Linux), then ran and connected it to my LAN. On my laptop I ran Jmeter with TCP Sampler.
After 5 minutes responding to 15 threads server stays on constant 80ms time of response. Then, after 8 minutes it starts to falling down:
time - avg response time
5mins - 80ms
8mins - 72ms
10mins - 44ms
12mins and more - 20ms
And it stays on this about 20ms. Why is that happening? Is there some cache mechanism or just some random conditions changing? I cant run the tests again and I have no idea where is the possibility to cache the sending data.

Answer (score 0):

How many hits per seconds are you getting?

The TCP sampler will NOT cache the results.
Maybe something in the OS is doing some caching?

Comment: It's about 100, I know that sampler isn't caching

Answer (score 0):

The answer maybe too late, but I would like to share my experience in a similar situation when I was debugging a performance issue.  Using a network sniffer to capture the packets, then look at a few sessions to check the response time. You can either prove or disprove the reported response time by traffic generator is correct or not and go from there. Good luck.